How can I downsize protruding pins from sensors to so I can use a smaller housing?
I'm trying to create a system where I continuously measure color data from a fluid. I've created a 3D-printed box where the pins fit; if they're configured in their out-of-the-box arrangement, what would be the best way to decrease the height of the sensor structure to obtain a more sleek design?
I suppose I could bend the pins as in the picture, but that doesn't sound so great. Would the best solution be de-soldering the out-of-the-box pins, attaching wires with male connectors, and soldering them into the now empty connections? (Although I don't trust my soldering that much, as the pins are very, very close)


@jsotola: the thing should fit into the black box. I have cropped the picture so that it takes less space on the screen.

Buy the sensor without pins and solder the wires directly to the board. You should do that anyway for a better mechanical and electrical connection.
The same applies to the Arduino or other micro-controller. Buy one without header and solder the wires.

Although I don't trust my soldering that much, as the pins are very, very close

Those pins are not close. It seems you haven't seen SMD components yet. They have a standard 2.54 mm (0.1 in) spacing. If you can't do it reliably, let it do someone else. Or go to a local amateur radio club and ask them to teach you soldering. Or maybe you just have the wrong tip for the soldering iron.


Unfortunately, not knowing this, I've finished my project's budget. I suppose I will be either: 1. trying to de-solder all those pins or 2. trying to wrap a wire around the already-in-place pins and solder them instead, then cover them with a shrinking tube. 3. Bite the bullet and pay out of pocket.
I'll train my soldering on some waste bits I've got, I suppose. It can't be harder than brain surgery...
Much appreciate the answer, by the way :)
